# c++ "#include" output explanation

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

Trying to understand how `#include` works. I'm reading that, during pre-procesing, it just replaces itself with the contents of the referenced file.

To verify, I create two files. A file named `otherfile` containing only the string `1234`, and a file `test.cpp` which contains

```
#include otherfile
abcd
```

I run `g++ -E test.cpp`, and the output I get is

```
# 1 "test.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 373 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "test.cpp" 2
# 1 "./wtf" 1
1234
# 2 "test.cpp" 2
abcd
```

Where do the rest of the lines come from, and what do they mean?

Comment: The output you see is specific to the gcc preprocessor.   For more information, have a look at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html  Note the references in that link to what the standard requires/allows versus what the gcc preprocessor actually does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Where do the rest of the lines come from

They are added by the pre-processor.

> and what do they mean?

As per the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html)

> Source file name and line number information is conveyed by lines of the form
>
> ```
> # linenum filename flags
> ```
>
> These are called linemarkers. They are inserted as needed into the output (but never within a string or character constant). They mean that the following line originated in file filename at line linenum. filename will never contain any non-printing characters; they are replaced with octal escape sequences.